# CakePHP: retrieve list with conditional arguments

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I'm having hard time to understand how to retrieve associated data with a conditional formatting.
I'm using CakePHP 3.7.9.

### Table products

```
id
name
customer_code
```

### Table orders

```
id
name
date
```

### Table item_orders

```
id
order_id
name
product_id
description
```

In a View (of another controller) I have two `select` controls. The first one is populated with `id|name` of the existing orders. When the user selects one, the second `select` control should be populated following this criteria:

- if `product_id` is not null -> retrieve `name (customer_code)` in the `products` table
- else use the `description` value

I use `ajax` to send the current `order_id` to the controller that should send back the html needed to populate the second `select`:

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(['block' => 'script', 'inline' => false]); ?>
    $(document).on('change', '#order-id', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': <?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')); ?> },
            url:  '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'ItemDeliveryNotes', 'action' => 'getOrderItems'));?>',
            data: { 'orderId': $('#order-id').val() },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#itemOrders').html(response.data.itemOrders);
            }
        });
    });
<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd(); ?>

public function getOrderItems()
{
    if ($this->request->is(['ajax', 'post']))
    {
        $id = $this->request->getData('orderId'); // <-- fixed
        $items = $this->getItems($id);
        $combo = [];
        foreach ($items as $key => $value)
        {
            $combo[] = "<option value='" . $key . "'>" . $value . "</option>";
        }

        $data = ['data' => ['itemOrders' => $combo]];
        return $this->json($data);
    }
}

private function getItems($id = null)
{
    $items = ???; // <-- here I need to retrieve the list as above
    return $items;
}
```

I'm able to fetch data from a single source, but in this case I don't understand how to compose the query.

### UPDATE

I tried with this code:

```
private function getItems($id = null)
{
    $items = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->ItemOrders->
        find('list', [
            'keyField' => 'id',
            'valueField' => function ($q) {
                $productId = $q->get('product_id');
                if ($productId) {
                    $code = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->ItemOrders->Products->field('code', ['id' => $productId]);
                    $customerCode = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->ItemOrders->Products->field('customerCode', ['id' => $productId]);
                    return $code . ' (' . $customerCode . ')';
                }
                else return $q->get('description');
            }
        ])->where(['order_id' => $id]);
    return $items;
}
```

It works fine but the `where` clause.
Without, I obtain all the items from all the orders using the requested criteria. 
But of course I'm interested only in the order that match the `$id`. Adding the `where` filter, nothing is returned.

Comment: You are sending `orderId`, but accessing `order_id`. That being said, issuing additional queries per row should really be avoided, filter on SQL level or contain the `Products` association and filter afterwards on PHP level.

Comment: I'm new to PHP and CakePHP. Would you mind to provide me a more detailed answer please? I don't fully understand your suggestion.

Comment: Actually, the problem was another typo: `'controller' => 'ItemDeliveryNotes'` instead of `ItemsDeliveryNotes`. With this corrections it works. It's weird it didn't raise an error, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you were sending the data as `orderId`, but accessing it as `order_id`, and as you've figured you were also using the wrong controller name.

You most likely didn't receive an error when generating the URL because you are using [**fallbacks**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#fallbacks-method), or manual catch-all routes, that is routes like `/:controller/:action`, which will match any controller/action. An error will be thrown when the request is being made to the non-existent endpoint, but you haven't defined an [**error/failure handler for your AJAX call**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR), so the error is being swallowed, still there should be something in your CakePHP error logs.

That being said, you really shouldn't issue additional queries per row (ie issuing queries in the `valueField` callback), instead filter either on SQL level, for example using a [**`CASE` expression**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements), or contain the `Products` association, so that you have all the data you need for filtering on PHP level, which should be as simple as:

```php
$items = $this->ItemsDeliveryNotes->Orders->ItemOrders
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => function (\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $row) {
            if ($row->has('product')) {
                return $row->product->name . ' (' . $row->product->customer_code . ')';
            }

            return $row->description;
        }
    ])
    ->contain('Products')
    ->where([
        'order_id' => $id
    ]);
```

Comment: Both versions of code return the same results. You say: "you really shouldn't issue additional queries per row". Can you please explain *why*? I just want to understand the underlying issues.

Comment: @Mark Because it's just unnecessary overhead that can easily be avoided. Your example looks like it will issue at least 2 queries per retrieved row (I assume the `field()` method queries the database), so if your list finder query would retrieve 100 item orders, it would issue at least 200 additional queries.